# Formatting table with .format

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I'm done this program below to show calorie expenditure for various physical activities, but The output of the table is uneven and I have to format it using .format. I have keep attempting different values to move it around but, nothing is really working.

---

```
# Constants
CANOEING = 256
HIKING = 438
ROLLER_BLADING = 548
TAE_KWON_DO = 752
TAI_CHI = 219
HOUR = 60

# Table Top
print("Calories for Various Activities for a 73 kg person")
print("")
 print("Activity          15 min    30 min    45 min    60 min    75 min    90 min")

# Table Results
for activity in range(1, 5 + 1):
    if activity == 1:
        print("Canoeing", end="")
    elif activity == 2:
        print("Hiking", end="")
    elif activity == 3:
    print("Roller Blading", end="")
    elif activity == 4:
        print("Tae kwon do", end="")
    elif activity == 5:
        print("Tai chi", end="")
    for time in range(15, 90 + 1, 15):
        canoe_time = time * CANOEING / HOUR
        hike_time = time * HIKING / HOUR
        roller_time = time * ROLLER_BLADING / HOUR
        tkd_time = time * TAE_KWON_DO / HOUR
        tc_time = time * TAI_CHI / HOUR
        if activity == 1:
            print("{:>10}{:>5.1f}".format(" ", canoe_time), end="")
        elif activity == 2:
            print("{:>12}{:>5.1f}".format(" ", hike_time), end="")
        elif activity == 3:
            print("{:>4}{:>5.1f}".format(" ", roller_time), end="")
        elif activity == 4:
            print("{:>7}{:>5.1f}".format(" ", tkd_time), end="")
        elif activity == 5:
            print("{:>11}{:>5.1f}".format(" ", tc_time), end="")
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to print in first column names with the same length. If name is shorter then add spaces at end or use `format()` to add spaces.

In other columns you have to use always the same length.

```
# Constants
CANOEING = 256
HIKING = 438
ROLLER_BLADING = 548
TAE_KWON_DO = 752
TAI_CHI = 219
HOUR = 60

# Table Top
print("Calories for Various Activities for a 73 kg person")
print("")
print("Activity          15 min    30 min    45 min    60 min    75 min    90 min")

# Table Results
for activity in range(1, 5 + 1):
    if activity == 1:
        title = "Canoeing"
    elif activity == 2:
        title = "Hiking"
    elif activity == 3:
        title = "Roller Blading"
    elif activity == 4:
        title = "Tae kwon do"
    elif activity == 5:
        title = "Tai chi"

    print("{:<14}".format(title), end="")

    for time in range(15, 90 + 1, 15):
        if activity == 1:
            value = time * CANOEING / HOUR
        elif activity == 2:
            value = time * HIKING / HOUR
        elif activity == 3:
            value = time * ROLLER_BLADING / HOUR
        elif activity == 4:
            value = time * TAE_KWON_DO / HOUR
        elif activity == 5:
            value = time * TAI_CHI / HOUR

        print("{:>10.1f}".format(value), end="")

    print("")
```

---

**EDIT:** you can use `|`, `-`, `+` to draw frames

```
# Constants
CANOEING = 256
HIKING = 438
ROLLER_BLADING = 548
TAE_KWON_DO = 752
TAI_CHI = 219
HOUR = 60

# Table Top
print("Calories for Various Activities for a 73 kg person")
print("")
print("Activity      |   15 min|   30 min|   45 min|   60 min|   75 min|   90 min|")
print("--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+")

# Table Results
for activity in range(1, 5 + 1):
    if activity == 1:
        title = "Canoeing"
    elif activity == 2:
        title = "Hiking"
    elif activity == 3:
        title = "Roller Blading"
    elif activity == 4:
        title = "Tae kwon do"
    elif activity == 5:
        title = "Tai chi"

    print("{:<14}|".format(title), end="")

    for time in range(15, 90 + 1, 15):
        if activity == 1:
            value = time * CANOEING / HOUR
        elif activity == 2:
            value = time * HIKING / HOUR
        elif activity == 3:
            value = time * ROLLER_BLADING / HOUR
        elif activity == 4:
            value = time * TAE_KWON_DO / HOUR
        elif activity == 5:
            value = time * TAI_CHI / HOUR

        print("{:>9.1f}|".format(value), end="")

    print("")

print("--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+")
```

result

```
Calories for Various Activities for a 73 kg person

Activity      |   15 min|   30 min|   45 min|   60 min|   75 min|   90 min|
--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Canoeing      |     64.0|    128.0|    192.0|    256.0|    320.0|    384.0|
Hiking        |    109.5|    219.0|    328.5|    438.0|    547.5|    657.0|
Roller Blading|    137.0|    274.0|    411.0|    548.0|    685.0|    822.0|
Tae kwon do   |    188.0|    376.0|    564.0|    752.0|    940.0|   1128.0|
Tai chi       |     54.8|    109.5|    164.2|    219.0|    273.8|    328.5|
--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

BTW: you can use `format()` to print header too.

---

There are modules to draw tables ie. [PrettyTable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PTable/0.9.0)

Comment: ah i see, then it must have been roller blading that messed me up due to extremely long name. I love you, thanks for your help :D